# MSI 970 Gaming USB 3.0 drivers

Tags: drivers, usb, msi

I recently switched to Ubuntu, with intents to make it my main OS. So far I've managed to get everything working correctly except my USB 3 ports. No matter what I plug in (I've tried flash drives, portable hard drives, and wireless adaptors) it receives power, but is never detected by the system.

I'm assuming this problem is due to a missing driver for my motherboard, an [MSI 970 gaming](http://us.msi.com/support/mb/970-GAMING.html).

There are no official linux drivers, but I was hoping someone here could point me to a site that might have some.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll find drivers for this anywhere. I suggest you submit a bug report to the kernel. It's a difficult process, but the Ubuntu kernel team will be happy to help. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Resolved it by adding in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft"
```

Then `sudo update-grub`, reboot and voilà!

Comment: While this may solve the issue, it would be nice if you explained what this new argument means.